# Klein-Gordon solution's Fourier image

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, klein-gordon-equation

I'm solving Klein-Gordon equation in order to get scalar field expression.
$$(\partial^2 + m^2)\phi=0$$
I expand solution $\phi$ into Fourier integral in momentum space:
$$\phi=\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\varphi(p)e^{-i\langle p,x\rangle },\quad \text{where } \langle p,x\rangle  \equiv p^0t-(p^1x^1 + p^2x^2 + p^3x^3)$$
And substitute in to equation, getting:
$$\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}(-p^2 + m^2)\varphi(p)e^{-i\langle p,x\rangle }=0 \Rightarrow (-p^2 + m^2)\varphi(p)=0$$
There a book tells that the solution of a gotten algebraic equation is $\varphi(p) = 2\pi\delta(m^2-p^2)\bar\varphi(p)$. I have some difficulties figuring out a couple of points considering this.

Since we've gotten a solution $\varphi$ in terms of generalized functions, then the equation is considered in distribution space, and such a result is somehow linked with a known result $xf(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = C\delta(x)$

So, the points are:

1. If I'm right and the eq is solved in terms of generalized functions, why in the solution $\varphi(p) = 2\pi\delta(m^2-p^2)\bar\varphi(p)$ is a function $\bar\varphi(p)$ dependent upon $p$ instead of constant $C$?
2. If $\varphi$ is distribution, then $\phi$ is distribution as well, at least in general case (Fourier is closed). So, we're searching for a distribution instead of ordinary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some general comments. The Dirac delta distribution you find merely constrains the values of $p$ that span the space of solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation. When you try to solve the KG equation with the ansatz $$\phi(x)=\int\dfrac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\tilde{\phi}(p)e^{ipx}\tag{1}$$

a priori any value of $p$ appears. The delta function $\delta(p^2-m^2)$ constrains to a subspace where $p^2-m^2=0$. So when you find $\tilde{\phi}(p)=\tilde{\varphi}(p)\delta(p^2-m^2)$ and substitute in (1) all that will happen is that you may integrate over the delta function, write $p^0=\pm \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$, and obtain one expansion where $p$ runs over only the subspace $p^2-m^2=0$ of the momentum space. This is a double-sheeted hyperboloid, each sheet corresponding to a sign of $p^0$. People then usually prefer to decompose (1) in two integrals, and in the one for $p^0=-\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$ change variables so as to have two integrals over the same hyperboloid which can be recombined. That's why one ends with something like $$\phi(x)=\int_{H_m^+}\dfrac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32p^0}(a(p)e^{-ipx}+a^\dagger(p)e^{ipx})\tag{2},$$
where $H_m^+$ is the space of all $p\in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ such that $p^2-m^2=0$ and $p^0>0$.

Now, given your specific questions:

1. In the one-dimensional case $xf(x)=0$ has only one variable in the game, $x$, and one constraint. Therefore the dependence on $x$ is fully determined and all you can have is a constant. Thus $f(x)=C\delta(x)$. In the case $(p^2-m^2)\tilde{\phi}(p)=0$ the matter is different. We have $p\in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and therefore we have four variables. Still we have only one constraint. The constraint will indeed restrict to a codimension one subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ but it cannot determine the complete dependence in $p$. As a result you end up with a function on that subspace, $\tilde{\phi}(p)=\tilde{\varphi}(p)\delta(p^2-m^2)$.

   If you want to think in a different way imagine that you introduce coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ of the form $(\lambda,\hat{p})$ where $p^2-m^2=\lambda^2$ and $\hat{p}$ are coordinates on the space of constant $\lambda$. Clearly your constraint only affects the dependence in $\lambda$ leaving the dependence on $\hat{p}$ undetermined.
2. To be fair quantum fields ought to be operator-valued distributions, so even though not usually spelled out, we are indeed considering $\phi(x)$ as a distribution. But not by the reason you are saying: observe that as soon as substitute the solution in terms of $\delta(p^2-m^2)$ in (1) the delta function gets eliminated by integrating against $p^0$ for instance and you are left with one integral over a three-dimensional space without remaining deltas.

Comment: 1. Can you please specify the source where I can read about multidimensional delta and its algebraic properties with proofs. I had been searching for, but didn't find anything. 

2. I'm also trying to figure out why do we solve algebraic equation in generalized functions instead of ordinary ones. It's because we're searching for distribution $\phi$ or there is another reason?
Really appreciate your help, and looking forward to your reply

Comment: Well, regarding the first question I believe this is treated in most mathematical methods books like Arfken or Butkov. If you want something more oriented towards mathematicians then perhaps this Math.SE thread will help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/distribution-theory-book. Still, let me emphasize that the delta appearing here is the one-dimensional one.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the thing is that the solution to $(p^2-m^2)\tilde{\phi}(p)=0$ with non-vanishing $\tilde{\phi}(p)$ *must* enforce the constraint $p^2-m^2=0$. If the constraint is not satisfied, then $\tilde{\phi}(p)$ *must* be zero. This is exactly what $\tilde{\phi}(p)=\tilde{\varphi}(p)\delta(p^2-m^2)$ accomplishes.

Comment: thank you! Regarding your second answer, I'm interested in why do we solve equation in terms of generalized functions instead of ordinary ones. There should be the reason why we consider equation to be solved in distributions space

Comment: How would you solve it otherwise? The equation $(p^2-m^2)\tilde{\phi}(p)=0$ implies that your $\tilde{\phi}(p)$ must vanish when $p^2-m^2\neq 0$. You can then go back to $$\phi(x)=\int \dfrac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\tilde{\phi}(p) e^{-ipx}$$ and say that this integral is just over the subspace of momentum space defined by $p^2-m^2=0$. This is exactly the same as saying that $\tilde{\phi}(p)=\tilde{\varphi}(p)\delta(p^2-m^2)$. But I believe I don't fully understand why you are confused about this.

Comment: Well, basically, I'm not confused - I wanna figure out from math point of view if there is any grounds, arising from physic concepts of QFT or another physics theory, which substantiate solving the equation in terms of generalized functions. 
You know, equations obtained by Fourier transform can be solved both with ordinary functions and distributions - the example, which may shed light, equation $x^mf(x) = 1$. In ordinary functions the solution will $f(x) = 1/x^m, x \neq 0$, while in distributions: $f(x) = P\frac{1}{x^m} + C_0\delta(x) + ... + C_m\delta^{(m-1)}(x)$.